# Integrate gives wrong result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Computing the integral of the Euclidian distance of two points in a plane, Mathematica seems to give a wrong result. This is a simple integral that should not be tricky and can easily be computed by hand. I wonder if this is a bug (and should be reported?), or whether there is something profound to say about this?

[image]

Ps. this is with Mathematica 11.

Comment: Please post copy-pastable code, not screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Don't you get an error with `NIntegrate`, before having the result?

Comment: Strange, on MMA 11.0.0.0 (Ubuntu 16.04) I get `1/15 (2 + Sqrt[2] + 5 ArcSinh[1])` for the first one (without the `10Pi/15`) which gives `0.51405` and an error with `NIntegrate` when no `Method` is specified. Note that `NIntegrate[
 Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2], {x, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 
  1}, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}]` gives `0.521405`, with an error however.

Comment: I can confirm anderstood's observation. (except that he/she forgot a 2 in the value specified ;D ). "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)". (Edit: LocalAdaptive as a method works without errors. [a little deviation in the accuracy though])

Comment: I'm getting the same results (including anderstood's comment) with `10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`.

Comment: Using NIntegrate I get the following error message: NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. ... Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.5214029934233115` and 1.5462735846294425`*^-6 for the integral and error

Comment: Also, this quadruple integral is confusing me. What are you trying to sum?